# Did I do the composition of $R_1$ and $R_2$ properly?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, solution-verification

I've been learning about compositions of relations. I was wondering if someone can critique my work to see if I've done it right.

Given a set $A = \{a,b,c,d\}$

Given $R_1 = \{ (a,b), (a,c), (d,d) \}$

Given $R_2 = \{ (a,c), (b,a), (b,c), (b,d), (d,c) \}$

Find $ R_1 \circ R_2 $ and $ R_2 \circ R_1 $

My working:

$$\begin{align} R_1 \circ R_2 &= \{ (b,b), (b,c), (b,d) \} \\
R_2 \circ R_1 &= \{ (a,a), (a,c), (a,d), (d,c) \}\end{align}$$

Comment: I edited your post to improve formatting. Please review the edit and keep it in mind for next time. For example, don't write only parts of an expression in math mode. Write the whole thing. So don't write `$A$={a,b,c,d}`, but rather `$A=\{a, b, c, d\}$`, as the result is much nicer: the first version returns "$A$={a,b,c,d}", the second returns $A=\{a, b, c, d\}$.

Comment: I think the first answer should also include $(d,d)$, since $(b,d)\in R_2$ and $(d,d)\in R_1$. Otherwise, looks great!

Comment: @GregMartin $(b, d)\in R_2$ and $(d, d)\in R_1$ means that $(b, d)$, not $(d,d)$ is a member of the compositum.

Comment: @5xum oops, good thing the OP is doing the problem and not me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your answers are correct.